# Codeigniter backup database (how much can it backup?)

Tags: codeigniter

When reading the manuel guide for Codeigniter, i notice under the database utilities that the backup feature says *"backing up very large databases may not be possible."*

What exactly does this mean? How much would it be able to backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From CodeIgniter's [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html#backup):

> Due to the limited execution time and memory available to PHP, backing up very large databases may not be possible.

The configuration of your server (hosting your website/CodeIgniter) will likely limit the **maximum execution time** of a PHP script and the total **memory available** to PHP. Determining what size database you can backup will depend entirely on your specific server configuration. Running this backup utility with *your* database on *your* server and benchmarking the results - CodeIgniter's [Benchmarking Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/benchmark.html) may help here - will help you determine what size database you can backup. You can potentially change your server's configuration to allocate more resources to PHP as required.

---

I decided to benchmark this backup function with a few different databases. This was just out of curiosity, so I wouldn't rely on these results, but they may be of interest.

**Database 1**

- 306.4 KB
- 78 Tables
- 279 rows

Results:

- Execution time: 0.0603s
- Peak memory usage:3 MB

**Database 2**

- 1 MB
- 11 Tables
- 165 rows

Results:

- Execution time: 0.0350s
- Peak memory usage: 3.25 MB

**Database 3**

- 16.6 MB
- 4 Tables
- 403 rows

Results:

- Execution time: 0.6335s
- Peak memory usage: 30.5 MB

**Database 4**

- 6.5 MB
- 9 Tables
- 93,289 rows

Results:

- Time taken: 7.1702s
- Peak memory usage: 91.25 MB

Comment: So is depends on my server settings? Not the settings of the server I backup?

Comment: Yes, correct. It may also depend on the hardware of your server - how much RAM it has. I'm benchmarking this backup function with a few databases now, I'll post my results soon. When benchmarking with a large(ish) database, I had to increase the memory available to PHP for the backup function to complete.